# LXML to write in unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, lxml

I am currently using lxml to write a file. I build the node and then I write it to a file using `etree.tostring(node, pretty_print=True)`. However, it seems to be using htmlencoding --

```
<Synopsis>
    Abila schlie&#223;lich die ersten sechs Aufgaben zu meistern. Wird der Junge auch 
</Synopsis>
```

In order to decipher it and get it into the format I want it in, I am currently doing:

```
>>> print HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape('Abila schlie&#223;lich die ersten sechs Aufgaben zu meistern. Wird der Junge auch')
Abila schließlich die ersten sechs Aufgaben zu meistern. Wird der Junge auch
```

How would I have this write in unicode, or is this not possible with `lxml` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can pass an encoding to `etree.tostring` method using the `encoding` parameter:

```
etree.tostring(node, pretty_print=True, encoding='unicode')
```

From the `etree.tostring` [docs](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring):

> You can also serialise to a Unicode string without declaration by
>   passing the `unicode` function as encoding (or `str` in Py3), or
>   the name 'unicode'.  This changes the return value from a byte string
>   to an unencoded unicode string.